# Speed up multiquery with Instagram api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram

I'm getting the images with the media/search endopoint passing a lat and lon like this

```
 url = Instagram.Config.apiHost + "/v1/media/search?lat=28.46555600&lng=-16.25113310&distance=5000&callback=?&client_id=" + Instagram.Config.clientID;
```

and then I'm gettin only the pics with a certain tag #instabeachpro,if the pic is not found I go trough the next set of pics adding the last pic created_time to the url with the max_timestamp parameter, here is the code I'm using

```
 (function(){
 var url,tags,menos,photos = new Array(),i=90;

 function search(){
    generateResource(tag;
    $.getJSON(url, toScreen);
 }
function init(){
    bindEventHandlers();
}
 function generateResource(){
    url = Instagram.Config.apiHost + "/v1/media/search?lat=28.46555600&lng=-16.25113310&distance=5000&callback=?&client_id=" + Instagram.Config.clientID;
   return url;
 }
function toScreen(){
    var next_url=url+"&max_timestamp="+data.data[data.data.length - 1].created_time;

    $.each(data.data, function(index, photo){
    i--;
   tags=photo.tags;
   menos=jQuery.inArray( "instabeachpro", tags );
   if(menos!=-1)
   { 
       $('div#photos-wrap').append("<div id='"+i+"' ><a href='"+photo.link+"'><img     src='"+photo.images.low_resolution.url+"'/></a></div><div><img class='second'    src='"+photo.user.profile_picture+"'/></div>"); 
   }
  else{
    i++;
   }


   });
   if(next_url!=undefined+"&callback=?" && i>=0){    
      console.log(i);
      pagination(next_url);
    }

 }
 function pagination(url)
 {
   $.getJSON(url, toScreen);
 }

   Instagram.App = {
search: search,
init: init
 };

  function bindEventHandlers(){
     $('body').on('click', '#loadObject', function(){
        url=$(this).attr('data-next-url');
        i=90;
       if(url=='undefined')
      {
         alert("undefined");
      }
     else{
        pagination(url);
        return false;
      }
  });
 }

 }());

 $(function(){
    Instagram.App.init();
    Instagram.App.search(); 

 });
```

This works but it's extremely slow and I have no idea what to do to speed it up, because the api doesn't support searching like I want to do, and i need to get al the pcitures with a certain tag IN a certain location, I have been told a number of times this is the only way to do it, but there has to be a faster way.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is extremely inefficient, since the tag you are searching is not popular and very small percentage of people use it, so getting API around location and then filtering by tag is expensive on number of API calls.

Search the other way round, make API call for the tag and then check for location for that photo. Check this implementation: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/tags#instabeachpro
You can get the tag photos and maps it on Google Maps, scroll to load more photos and see that very few of the `#instabeachpro` photos are tagged with location

Comment: Yeah I thought on making it the other way arround, but I don't want to map it in google i Just want to show them,an example, photos near me, i want to get all pics with the hashtag #instabeachpro in a 5km radius near me

Comment: So yeah, I was being dumb, all I need to do was calculate the distance between the lat and long from the pic and the lat and long where the user was, if the distance is <= than 5km I show the pic.But than you for the answer